# server running IIS and Apache: setting up SSL

Tags: php, apache, iis, ssl, webserver

One of my clients have a server running both IIS and Apache. IIS is on port 80 and Apache is on port 8081. I am working on an application that will be running on Apache and this application needs to be configure so that it uses SSL.

The client already purchased the SSL certificate from Godaddy but when trying to generate the CSR file, it asks for certain information like the Common Name (fully qualified domain name, or URL, you are securing. I am having from with this particular section: Common Name.

The application's URL is http://apps.patria.com.do:8081/Cobros_Online/. When I use this as the URL, it tells me it is not valid. After doing some research, it looks like it cannot contain port number. How can I fix this? I can't use the default port 80 because IIS is on port 80.

So, for example, http://apps.patria.com.do/, will take you to another application running on IIS.

What can I do to make the URL acceptable?

Thanks in advance!